# Dexie: How do I add a tab to the beginning?

Tags: javascript, web, browser, electron, dexie

We make an open source browser.

Please correct the add-on of the tabs. It is necessary that the tab is added to the beginning. Now the tab is added to the end:

```
var newTab = tabs.add({}, tabs.getIndex(tabs.getSelected()) + 1)
```

[link to the GitHub repository](https://github.com/doreminiature/miniature/blob/master/js/navbar/addTabButton.js)

Tried these options:

```
tabs.add({}, 0)
tabs.add({})
tabs.put({})
```

How do I add a tab to the beginning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
tabs.add({}, tabs[0]);
```

What this does is it tells js to add the element at the beginning of the list (array). You can read more [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_select_add.asp).

Hope this helps!